# Get query string variable name in Django

Tags: python, django, templates

I am new to Django, so my problem might be simple. I need to write a template, that would echo information from a query string. The string looks something like that:
http://127.0.0.1:8000/echo/?a=1
The problem is, that query name might change from 'a' to something else, and I need to echo it accordingly. I know how to capture value from that string, but I don't know how to capture name. Please help.

```
def echo(request):
return render(request, 'echo.html', context={
    'get': request.GET.get('a'),
    'post': request.GET.get('b')
})


<!--DOCTYPE html -->
<html>
<body>
{% if request.method == 'GET' %}
    <h1> get a= {{ get }} statement is empty </h1>
{% elif request.method == 'POST' %}
    <h2> post b= {{ post }} statement is empty</h2>
{% endif %}
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Uhm, `request.META['QUERY_STRING']`

Comment: Thank you! That did the trick.

Comment: @Riane Accept the his answer if it helped you.

Comment: Is there a way I can get just the query name, without the value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [HttpRequest.META](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.META)

```
request.META['QUERY_STRING']
```

docs:

> QUERY_STRING – The query string, as a single (unparsed) string.